# How to get/set the rootViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Now,I gonna Develop an App ,which wants to switch from many different Views irregularly,also the views need to load large resources,AKA,it's hard to manage memory.Are there any good solustion?

PS：I created a ViewController as RootViewController,and When a button was Touch,run the code as

> "ViewController=newController"

.The problem came,The new View loaded wrong way,it rotate so that couldn't show in a correct way.

I google for the solution,some one said ,I should replace the rootViewController,just like that,

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController=newController;
```

But I can't get/set the rootViewController in other class though it's a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Why not having a class that handles all the view switches ?

This article describes an architecture that might be helpfull: http://www.mikeziray.com/2010/01/27/handling-your-initial-view-controllers-for-iphone/comment-page-1/#comment-607